# Neo4j apoc.algo.aStar block nodes/must have nodes

Tags: java, neo4j, a-star

I want to find shortest paths in neo4j.

My nodes have `x` and `y` coordinates and my relationships have a property with `distance`.

The `A*` procedure works fine to find the shortest path. 
But I also need to be able to block some nodes or to choose nodes that have to be in the resulting path (kind of the `TSP`).

My colleagues and I feel like a Graphdatabase should be able to solve this kind of problems from scratch.

The amount of must have nodes wont be that high (prbly 1-5). I'm already trying to solve this on my own but I think this is a quite popular thing and should be a part of neo4j.

PS: I already managed to write my own `estimateEvaluator` to filter out the block nodes. I'm still stuck on the `TSP`. I thought of creating a additional graph including the start and end nodes and all must have nodes and all their distances between each other(Cartesian product + `A*`). After that I would try to find the Hamiltonian path.

PS2:
Here is a graph. I only have `NODE` as nodetype. All nodes can possibly be start-, end-, block- or must have node.

```
CREATE (n:NODE{NODE_ELID:'START',COORD_X:0,COORD_Y:0})
CREATE (m1:NODE{NODE_ELID:'MID1',COORD_X:1,COORD_Y:1})
CREATE (m2:NODE{NODE_ELID:'MID2',COORD_X:3,COORD_Y:1})
CREATE (m3:NODE{NODE_ELID:'MID3',COORD_X:1,COORD_Y:2})
CREATE (m4:NODE{NODE_ELID:'MID4',COORD_X:2,COORD_Y:2})
CREATE (m5:NODE{NODE_ELID:'MID5',COORD_X:3,COORD_Y:2})
CREATE (m6:NODE{NODE_ELID:'MID6',COORD_X:1,COORD_Y:3})
CREATE (m7:NODE{NODE_ELID:'MID7',COORD_X:3,COORD_Y:3})
CREATE (m8:NODE{NODE_ELID:'MID8',COORD_X:4,COORD_Y:3})
CREATE (m9:NODE{NODE_ELID:'MID9',COORD_X:5,COORD_Y:3})
CREATE (m10:NODE{NODE_ELID:'MID10',COORD_X:5,COORD_Y:4})
CREATE (m11:NODE{NODE_ELID:'MID11',COORD_X:3,COORD_Y:5})
CREATE (m12:NODE{NODE_ELID:'MID12',COORD_X:4,COORD_Y:5})
CREATE (m13:NODE{NODE_ELID:'MID13',COORD_X:3,COORD_Y:6})
CREATE (m14:NODE{NODE_ELID:'MID14',COORD_X:3,COORD_Y:7})
CREATE (m15:NODE{NODE_ELID:'MID15',COORD_X:5,COORD_Y:7})
CREATE (m16:NODE{NODE_ELID:'MID16',COORD_X:3,COORD_Y:8})
CREATE (m17:NODE{NODE_ELID:'MID17',COORD_X:4,COORD_Y:8})
CREATE (n1:NODE{NODE_ELID:'END',COORD_X:6,COORD_Y:6})
CREATE (mu1:NODE{NODE_ELID:'MUST1',COORD_X:2,COORD_Y:1})
CREATE (mu2:NODE{NODE_ELID:'MUST2',COORD_X:2,COORD_Y:4})
CREATE (b1:NODE{NODE_ELID:'BLOCK1',COORD_X:2,COORD_Y:3})
CREATE (b2:NODE{NODE_ELID:'BLOCK2',COORD_X:4,COORD_Y:7})
CREATE (n)-[r1:CONNECTED_TO{DISTANCE:1.4}]->(m1)
CREATE (m1)-[r2:CONNECTED_TO{DISTANCE:1}]->(mu1)
CREATE (m1)-[r3:CONNECTED_TO{DISTANCE:1}]->(m3)
CREATE (m3)-[r4:CONNECTED_TO{DISTANCE:1}]->(m6)
CREATE (mu1)-[r5:CONNECTED_TO{DISTANCE:1}]->(m4)
CREATE (mu1)-[r6:CONNECTED_TO{DISTANCE:1}]->(m2)
CREATE (m4)-[r7:CONNECTED_TO{DISTANCE:1.4}]->(m7)
CREATE (m4)-[r8:CONNECTED_TO{DISTANCE:1}]->(b1)
CREATE (m7)-[r9:CONNECTED_TO{DISTANCE:1.4}]->(mu2)
CREATE (b1)-[r10:CONNECTED_TO{DISTANCE:1}]->(mu2)
CREATE (m6)-[r11:CONNECTED_TO{DISTANCE:1.4}]->(mu2)
CREATE (mu1)-[r12:CONNECTED_TO{DISTANCE:1.4}]->(m5)
CREATE (m2)-[r13:CONNECTED_TO{DISTANCE:1}]->(m5)
CREATE (m5)-[r14:CONNECTED_TO{DISTANCE:1.4}]->(m8)
CREATE (m8)-[r15:CONNECTED_TO{DISTANCE:1}]->(m9)
CREATE (m9)-[r16:CONNECTED_TO{DISTANCE:1}]->(m10)
CREATE (m10)-[r17:CONNECTED_TO{DISTANCE:1.4}]->(m12)
CREATE (m12)-[r18:CONNECTED_TO{DISTANCE:1.4}]->(m13)
CREATE (mu2)-[r19:CONNECTED_TO{DISTANCE:1.4}]->(m11)
CREATE (m11)-[r20:CONNECTED_TO{DISTANCE:1}]->(m13)
CREATE (m13)-[r21:CONNECTED_TO{DISTANCE:1}]->(m14)
CREATE (m14)-[r22:CONNECTED_TO{DISTANCE:1}]->(m16)
CREATE (m16)-[r23:CONNECTED_TO{DISTANCE:1}]->(m17)
CREATE (m17)-[r24:CONNECTED_TO{DISTANCE:1.4}]->(m15)
CREATE (m15)-[r25:CONNECTED_TO{DISTANCE:1.4}]->(n1)
CREATE (m13)-[r26:CONNECTED_TO{DISTANCE:1.4}]->(b2)
CREATE (b2)-[r27:CONNECTED_TO{DISTANCE:1}]->(m15)
CREATE (b2)-[r28:CONNECTED_TO{DISTANCE:1}]->(m17)
```

Did I miss something while researching? How to solve this properly?

Comment: Can you give an example of graph with some path result that details `block nodes` and `nodes that have to be in the resulting path ` ?

Comment: The nodes should only be blocked for the `A*`, not generally. Like `apoc.algo.aStar(startNode, endNode, 'KNOWS|<WORKS_WITH|IS_MANAGER_OF>', 'distance','lat','lon','block nodes', 'must-have nodes')`